# Smoothly change position of images

Tags: java, libgdx

I implemented like this http://prntscr.com/4k6vze
But the mine main problem if i drag on the screen the picture cant change smoothly. 
I draw like this state is how can i detect left or right move.

```
    int before=state-1;
    if(before>-1)
        batcher.draw(text.get(before), 16,200, 64, 64);

    batcher.draw(text.get(state), 96, 200,128, 128);

    int after=state+1;
    if(after<3)
        batcher.draw(text.get(after), 240, 200, 64, 64);

    batcher.draw(Assets.arrow,320, 32, -64, 64);
    batcher.end();
```

and second problem is I must make touched up if i want change picture (change picture means if make a pan left means the artic is in the place of highway and highway is on the position on cave ?):

```
public class SimpleDirectionGestureDetector extends GestureDetector {
    public interface DirectionListener {
        void onLeft();

        void onRight();

        void onUp();

        void onDown();
    }

    public SimpleDirectionGestureDetector(DirectionListener directionListener) {
        super(new DirectionGestureListener(directionListener));
    }

    private static class DirectionGestureListener extends GestureAdapter{
        DirectionListener directionListener;

        public DirectionGestureListener(DirectionListener directionListener){
            this.directionListener = directionListener;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean fling(float velocityX, float velocityY, int button) {
            if(Math.abs(velocityX)>Math.abs(velocityY)){
                if(velocityX>0){
                    directionListener.onRight();
                }else{
                    directionListener.onLeft();
                }
            }else{
                if(velocityY>0){
                    directionListener.onDown();
                }else{                                  
                    directionListener.onUp();
                }
            }
            return super.fling(velocityX, velocityY, button);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Removed C++ tag because `public class X extends Y` certainly isn't C++

Comment: i am not add c++ your admin add this :) I am programing in java

Comment: That's not an admin, I think it's a script that guesses the language because you forgot to tag it yourself. Anyway, I now added the java tag.